# Extract numbers from strings including '|'

Tags: regex, string, r, split

I have data where some of the items are numbers separated by "|", like:

```
head(mintimes)
[1] "3121|3151" "1171"      "1351|1381" "1050"      ""          "122" 
head(minvalues)
[1] 14    10    11    31 Inf    22
```

What I would like to do is extract all the times and match them to the minvalues. To end up with something like:

```
times    values
3121     14
3151     14
1171     10
1351     11
1381     11
1050     31
122      22
```

I've tried to `strsplit(mintimes, "|")` and I've tried `str_extract(mintimes, "[0-9]+")` but they don't seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`|` is a regular expression *metacharacter*.  When used literally, these special characters need to be escaped either with `[]` or with `\\` (or you could use `fixed = TRUE` in some functions).  So your call to `strsplit()` should be

```
strsplit(mintimes, "[|]")
```

or

```
strsplit(mintimes, "\\|")
```

or

```
strsplit(mintimes, "|", fixed = TRUE)
```

Regarding your other try with `stringr` functions, `str_extract_all()` seems to do the trick.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(mintimes, "[0-9]+")
```

**To get your desired result**,

```
> mintimes <- c("3121|3151", "1171", "1351|1381", "1050", "", "122") 
> minvalues <- c(14, 10, 11, 31, Inf, 22)
> s <- strsplit(mintimes, "[|]")
> data.frame(times = as.numeric(unlist(s)), 
             values = rep(minvalues, sapply(s, length)))
#   times values
# 1  3121     14
# 2  3151     14
# 3  1171     10
# 4  1351     11
# 5  1381     11
# 6  1050     31
# 7   122     22
```

Comment: Ok mister quick draw. ;)

Comment: I thought OP wanted not only to split on the vertical pipe but also match the values to the times.  One approach might be to duplicate the times variable in times2 column, then write something like ifelse(grep("\\|"), do nothing (i.e., leave both times1 and times2 as is, else "" to delete the unneeded time2.  Then, create a data frame in the format of his example.  Such wizardry is manifestly beyond this newbie.

Comment: @user2583119, I've updated my answer to include the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

By default `strsplit` splits using a regular expression and "|" is a special character in the regular expression syntax. You can either escape it

```
strsplit(mintimes,"\\|")
```

or just set fixed=T to not use regular expressions

```
strsplit(mintimes,"|", fixed=T)
```

Answer (score 3):

I have written a function called [**`cSplit`**](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733) that is useful for these types of things. You can get it from my Gist: https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/11380733

Usage would be:

```
cSplit(data.table(mintimes, minvalues), "mintimes", "|", "long")
#    mintimes minvalues
# 1:     3121        14
# 2:     3151        14
# 3:     1171        10
# 4:     1351        11
# 5:     1381        11
# 6:     1050        31
# 7:      122        22
```

---

It also has a "wide" setting, in case that would be at all useful to you:

```
cSplit(data.table(mintimes, minvalues), "mintimes", "|", "wide")
#    minvalues mintimes_1 mintimes_2
# 1:        14       3121       3151
# 2:        10       1171         NA
# 3:        11       1351       1381
# 4:        31       1050         NA
# 5:       Inf         NA         NA
# 6:        22        122         NA
```

Note: The output is a `data.table`.

Comment: This could probably be updated to `library(splitstackshape)` now, right?

Comment: @RichardScriven, there are probably at least a couple of dozen answers on SO that have `cSplit` as part of the answer--not prepared to update them all (also because that bumps questions to the front of the "active" page and I wouldn't want that to happen).

Comment: @RichardScriven, as an alternative, I've added a `message` to the `cSplit` Gist that mentions that it's now part of "splitstackshape". That should help :-)

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you need to escape the `|` to include it literally in a regular expression. As always, we can skin this cat many ways, and here's one way to do it with `stringr`:

```
x <- c("3121|3151", "1171", "1351|1381", "1050", "", "122")

library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(x, "\\d+"))

# [1] "3121" "3151" "1171" "1351" "1381" "1050" "122"
```

This won't work as expected if you have any decimal points in a character string of numbers, so the following (which says to match anything but `|`) might be safer:

```
unlist(str_extract_all(x, '[^|]+'))

# [1] "3121" "3151" "1171" "1351" "1381" "1050" "122"
```

Either way, you might want to wrap the result in `as.numeric`.

Answer (score 2):

And here's another solution using `stri_split_fixed` from the `stringi` package. As an added value, we also play with `mapply` and `do.call`.

Input data:

```
mintimes <- c("3121|3151", "1171", "1351|1381", "1050", "", "122") 
minvalues <- c(14, 10, 11, 31, Inf, 22)
```

Split `mintimes` w.r.t. `|` and convert to numeric:

```
library("stringi")    
mintimes <- lapply(stri_split_fixed(mintimes, "|"), as.numeric)
## [[1]]
## [1] 3121 3151
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] 1171
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] 1351 1381
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] 1050
## 
## [[5]]
## [1] NA
## 
## [[6]]
## [1] 122
```

Column-bind each `minvalues` with corresponding `mintimes`:

```
tmp <- mapply(cbind, mintimes, minvalues)
## [[1]]
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,] 3121   14
## [2,] 3151   14
## 
## [[2]]
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,] 1171   10
## 
## [[3]]
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,] 1351   11
## [2,] 1381   11
## 
## [[4]]
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,] 1050   31
## 
## [[5]]
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]   NA  Inf
## 
## [[6]]
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]  122   22
```

Row-bind all the 6 matrices & remove `NA`-rows:

```
res <- do.call(rbind, tmp)
res[!is.na(res[,1]),]
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,] 3121   14
## [2,] 3151   14
## [3,] 1171   10
## [4,] 1351   11
## [5,] 1381   11
## [6,] 1050   31
## [7,]  122   22
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the output you want, try something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

Split.Times <- function(x) {
  mintimes <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x$mintimes), "\\|")))
  return(data.frame(mintimes = mintimes, minvalues = x$minvalues, stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
}

df <- data.frame(mintimes, minvalues, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df %>%
  filter(mintimes != "") %>%
  group_by(mintimes) %>%
  do(Split.Times(.))
```

This produces:

```
  mintimes minvalues
1     1050        31
2     1171        10
3      122        22
4     1351        11
5     1381        11
6     3121        14
7     3151        14
```

(I borrowed from [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249351) - which is pretty much the same question/problem)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `qdap` package approach:

```
mintimes <- c("3121|3151", "1171", "1351|1381", "1050", "", "122") 
minvalues <- c(14, 10, 11, 31, Inf, 22)

library(qdap)
list2df(setNames(strsplit(mintimes, "\\|"), minvalues), "times", "values")

##   times values
## 1  3121     14
## 2  3151     14
## 3  1171     10
## 4  1351     11
## 5  1381     11
## 6  1050     31
## 7   122     22
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:punct:]

```
strsplit(mintimes, "[[:punct:]]")
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this in general. If you have any decimal points in a character vector of numbers, and use that pattern, you will break your data.